# Raspberry Pi with SMBus SmartBattery

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux, smbus

I'm trying to interface a Raspberry Pi with the [mini-box OpenUPS](http://www.mini-box.com/). It claims to implement the [Smart Battery SMBus specifications](http://sbs-forum.org/specs/sbdat110.pdf).

I can read data from the device using the i2c_smbus_read_word_data() function [as defined in the Linux Kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol).

So, my basic problem is this: When the device is booted for the first time, and I perform the first read, all the data is messed up. I get negative numbers, and none of it makes sense.

But, if I perform a single byte read, then all following word reads give the correct data.

It's almost as if the byte order is getting messed up in a buffer someplace, and it takes a single byte read to straighten it out. But why doesn't it work the first time?

Comment: Odd that the site complained that a hyperlink directly to the OpenUPS product page was 'not allowed'.

Comment: BTW, 'asking about asking' and putting thanks / nametags in question posts on EE.SE are discouraged activities, and will end up getting edited out.

Comment: This might be better asked at [RPi.SE](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact same thing. Do you have any code for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. That was four years ago, and I have since moved on from that company.

However, IIRC, we ended up using the USB interface and a daemon of some sort. We then communicated with the daemon via bash.